# php how get a value of json?

Tags: php, json

I have this data

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
print_r($result);
// stdClass Object ( [d] => {"id":10} )
$id = ?;
```

How can I get a value of id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$result` is an object, you have to use property notation to access its components.

```
$id = json_decode($result->d)->id;
```

You need the extra `json_decode` because the value of `$result->d` is another JSON string, not an object or array.

Comment: It doesn't write me the id, it writes just {

Comment: See my updated answer. It would be better if you used `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, so the types of all the values would be more obvious.

Comment: You may want to check the application that created the original JSON, as it's strange to encode the values before encoding the whole structure. That's why the double decode is necessary.

Comment: yes, that "d" value is string need to convert in to json object

Answer (score 0):

You would get value with following

```
$obj_result = json_decode($result->d);
echo $obj_result->id;
```

By this way you will get id value 10

Comment: It doesn't write me the id, it writes just {

Comment: Put echo before the statement, that will show result of id. echo will show 10 on your Browser.

Comment: The value of `$result->d` is the string `'{"id":10}'`, not an array, so you can't index it.